# The name Nataliyah/Natali (is it Jewish?)

Tags: gentiles, names, etymology

Where does the name Natalia come from? I ask this because many many Jewish girls, even religious ones, use this as a name. I always thought that it is a feminine version of Naftali, is that true? Or is it a name that comes from the wicked queen Ataliah? Or is it just a non Jewish name/an influence from non jews? Many Russians use this name to, but we all know people all over the world (non jews) use Jewish/biblical names a lot.

תודה רבה חביבי

Comment: Habibi, this is not off topic! stop!

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalia_(given_name)) writes:

> Natalia is a female given name with the original Late Latin meaning of
>   "Christmas Day" (cf. Latin natale domini). It is currently used in
>   this form
>   in Italian, Romanian,Spanish, Portuguese, Greek, Russian, Ukrainian,
>   and Polish.[1] Other forms and spellings
>   include Natalie/Nathalie (French, English and German), Natálie
>   (Czech), Natália/Nathália
>   (Portuguese, Slovak and Hungarian), Natalya (Russian), Nataliya or Nataliia (Ukrainian),
>   Natalija (Croatian, Latvian, Serbian, Slovene and Macedonian)[2]and
>   Natàlia (Catalan).

From this article, it seems that the name has distinctly not got Jewish roots.

Comment: IIRC, Natal as a root refers to birth, here specifically the birth of Jesus. Maybe Nittelya would be a better name.

Comment: @Danno  - you mean as in "nittel-nacht"?

Comment: Yes -- some connect the NTL of notein ta'am lifgam with the NTL of the birth. (sorry I didn't tag you but sometimes when I try to, it doesn't work)

Comment: I like the name, but after reading this I'm not sure if I would like to name my daughter that...

Comment: There is a website I looked at (not a Jewish one) that says Natalia means "Given by G-d." I assume they draw that from the Hebrew word נתן? They mention Nathan the Prophet in the thing so maybe....?